# What version is my VPS?

Tags: linux, debian

I want to know what version of Linux is installed on my VPS, so I can reinstall the same image again.

This is the information I have:

```
# uname -a
Linux chicken 2.6.32-308.el5.028stab099.3 #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 15:56:00 MSK
2012 i686 GNU/Linux

# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-308.el5.028stab099.3 (root@rhel5-build-x64) (gcc 
version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)) #1 SMP Wed Mar 7 15:56:00 MSK 2012
```

The latter says Red Hat, but I'm really convinced it's NOT! There is no `rpm` installed, but `apt-get` is. I think it must be Ubuntu or Debian.

The VPS-admin tool lets me install both Ubuntu and Debian, and there are several versions to choose between for each. So if possible I would like to know the version number too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good news is your sanity is *mostly* intact

You're using a openvz, lxc or other container based vps, and your host is using RHEL as a host. You need to use `lsb_release` or some other tool that does *not* rely on the the kernel version to tell what you are really running. Most cheap VPSes in effect use containers running on the host's kernel (which are a lot more efficient for large numbers of simple VMs running windows), so you'll see the host's kernel (and its OS information) rather than the guest's.

On my vpses I usually run ubuntu LTS, so 12.04 at the moment - this is an openvz one, which I believe is similar to what you run.

while uname -a says

```
Linux server 2.6.32-042stab076.8 #1 SMP Tue May 14 20:38:14 MSK 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

which doesn't really tell me anything about what distro

while cat /proc/version says

```
Linux version 2.6.32-042stab076.8 (root@rh6-build-x64) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue May 14 20:38:14 MSK 201
```

so.. red hat, apparently version 6... which I know isn't the case

lsb_release tells me

```
root@someserver:~# lsb_release --all
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Which is what I thought I was running

Comment: And to add more confusion to that, `root@rh6-build-x64` is just the username + hostname of the system that *compiled* this kernel.

Comment: oh, yes, that too - I completely missed that.

Comment: Another thing you can look at is the presence of /etc/debian_version or /etc/redhat_version. Ubuntu includes the debian_version file and centos includes the redhat_version file, but it'll get you in the right family to start.